# Множественное  число слова "возникновение"

Tags: морфология

Можно ли употреблять слово «возникновение» во мн. числе? Например: "нередки возникновения правовых коллизий".

Answer (score 1):

ВОЗНИКНОВЕ́НИЕ, я, ***мн. нет***, ср. (книжн.).
Начало чего-н., появление, зарождение.В. чувства. Легенда о возникновении Рима.
Яндекс.Словари › Толковый словарь Ушакова, 1935-1940

Множественного числа у этого существительного нет.

Answer (score 1):

Слово ВОЗНИКНОВЕНИЕ, действительно, употребляется только в единственном числе (singularia tantum), как и многие другие отглагольные существительные. Ваше предложение лучше перестроить: "*Нередки случаи возникновения правовых коллизий*."

Answer (score 0):

Множественное число действительно лексически ненормативно. 
Но в вашем случае нет никакой необходимости во множественном числе.

"Нередко возникновение правовых коллизий" - здесь и так ясное, что речь идёт о множесивенных случаях.

Comment: Фраза как-то не звучит. Слово "нередко" требует какого-то глагола: "нередко возникают правовые коллизии". Если оставлять существительное (довольно, впрочем, неуклюжее), мне больше нравится вариант @olsa

Comment: "Это событие нередко" - зачем тут глагол?  
Тем более "возникновение" - существительное отглагольное.  
Но если говорить в теминах "нравится" - "не нравится", то мне вообще ни один из предложенных вариантов не по душе. Фраза ни о чем, для объема.

Comment: Ну почему ни о чем, коллизии-то правда возникают. Но, конечно, канцелярит.